When can radix-3 NTT faster than radix-2 NTT?
I am a beginner in Lattice based cryptography and now I am encountering some cryptography algorithms using NTT.
And I am trying to change the NTT in algorithms and I am going to make an appoche to use an other radix NTT such as radix-3 NTT.
And When can this help to improve the performance of Lattice cryptography,especially efficiency.

A radix-3 NTT will have fewer butterfly operations (for similar Lattice sizes), but each one is more complex.  It's not immediately obvious which factor would dominate - these sorts of speed questions are likely to be both implementation (CPU) dependent, as well as on the details of the operations.  Hence, pick a typical platform, implement them both, and compare.

so you mean there is a possibility for radix-3 faster than radix-2?It seems very interesting for me so please give me a detail.

Possibly, I don't personally know of anyone who has explored it.  On the other hand, it's likely to be quite implementation dependent.  If you want to try to explore yourself, knock yourself out.

I see the point and the main problem for radix-3 is that additional attack like side channel attack can be  more possible than radix-2.So your idea is?

Well, radix-3 is just as linear as radix-2, and so it should be just as threshold friendly.  On the other hand, the prime for radix-2 must end in 00000001 in binary - the prime for radix-3 would be in the form $a3^k + 1$, and wouldn't have such a simple binary representation.  I would naively expect that, if there is any side channel difference, that such a prime without a simple form would be a bit more resistant.

It is worth mentioning that I don't think the general question "When can this help to improve the performance of Lattice cryptography" has had any proposed answers. I don't recall anyone claiming radix 3 > radix 2 for any operation/parameter set. That being said, I've only seen a couple papers talking about radix != 2, so it is possible other options could have merits sometimes.
